# Is it possible to get generator tag removed from Joomla sites without interfering core framework?

Tags: cms, extensions, overrides, plugin

Is it possible to get the generator tag removed from Joomla sites without interfering with the core framework. I personally feel this is an irritating aspect of the source code and makes websites easily attacked if some security flaw in a particular version is exploited.

To explain it in detail: If some flaw is exploited in, say Joomla 3.2, then all websites based on Joomla 3.2 are targets and those websites can easily be found using generator tags. So I want to get rid of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once I have used a tiny plugin called ByeByeGenerator ( http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/generator-tag/12556 ), which removed the generator tag immediately!

Give it a try!

Comment: I would like to add there are several plugins which allow to change the generator tags. There is a whole category in JED dedicated to this problem:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/generator-tag

Answer (score 12):

If you use a custom template (or you write your own) you can easily remove the generator tag by putting the following code at the top of your template's `index.php` file.

`$this->setGenerator(null);`

Comment: Only hindrance being if I am using third party template and update the same later, all my changes will be lost.

Comment: That's true. I'm commenting from a developer standpoint where we do full service Joomla for the client where we build the templates for them. I forget not everyone does that.

Comment: The following link WANT TO REMOVE THE GENERATOR META TAG FROM YOUR JOOMLA AND WORDPRESS PAGE CODING? may provide further insight to Don's answer. http://cmsenergizer.com/website-energy-guide/36-want-to-remove-the-generator-meta-tag-from-your-page-coding-a-simple-edit-to-your-template-file-will-do-it

Comment: Whilst the answer has already been accepted, this is the best way to remove the generator tag.

Answer (score 5):

In the most current versions of Joomla (3.x), doesn't this setting in the Global Configuration do what you need, and hide the generator info:

[image: screenshot from Joomla 3 Global Configuration "Show Joomla Version"]

Comment: That's just the version number in the generator. The generator meta tag still shows with Joomla in. Just without a version number.

Comment: I would agree with what you hopped, this should hide it but it just hides the version. My guess is that by keeping the generator tag they can use google or a spider to find how many sites are running joomla so it doesnt server the marketing to have an option to remove it

Answer (score 0):

There is another free alternative to ByeBye Generator, as it's functionality is a bit limited. The Joomla metadata suite plugin allows you to remove the generator tag or brand it.

You can also remove the author tag, and add in additional metadata items for your social profiles.

Download: https://webdesignandcompany.com/products/joomla-metadata-suite/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link didn't work for me

Comment: The website dos not seem contactable right now.